# How to check if the location of a node is included in another one?

Tags: ios, swift, location, sknode

I'm trying to check if a node is located into another one : for example a balloon in a big rectangle which is moving. If the balloon is no more in the rectangle,  I'd like the balloon to disappear.

I've tried with the did begin contact function but it doesn't work.

Thanks for Your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 2 `SKSpriteNode(s)` with the **same parent**

```
let spriteA = SKSpriteNode()
let spriteB = SKSpriteNode()

let parent = SKNode()
parent.addChild(spriteA)
parent.addChild(spriteB)
```

we can check if the `position` point of `spriteA` is within the frame (bounding box) of `spriteB` with this line

```
CGRectContainsPoint(spriteB.frame, spriteA.position)
```

### Intersection

Alternatively we can also check for **intersection** between the bounding boxes of the sprites writing

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(spriteA.frame, spriteB.frame)
```

### When spriteA and spriteB do NOT have the same parent

Now let's consider this scenario

```
let spriteA = SKSpriteNode()
let spriteB = SKSpriteNode()

let scene = SKScene()
let parent = SKNode()
scene.addChild(spriteA)
scene.addChild(parent)
parent.addChild(spriteB)
```

To check whether `spriteA.position` is inside the `spriteB.frame`, first of all we must convert the `spriteA.position` to the `spriteB` coordinates system.

```
let spriteAPositionWithSpriteBCoordindates = spriteA.convertPoint(spriteA.position, toNode: spriteB)
```

Now we can call the `CGRectContainsPoint` function

```
CGRectContainsPoint(spriteB.frame, spriteAPositionWithSpriteBCoordindates)
```

Comment: Thank You very much for this quick and complete answer. It solved the issue.